Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer]
Sqs config class there setting the  attribute value and create new queqeMessing template
@Configuration
@EnableSqs
public class SqsConfig {

    @Bean
    public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
        return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSqs);

    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerAddAnaplanListQueue(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setAutoStartup(true);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setWaitTimeOut(1);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setBackOffTime(Long.valueOf(20000));
        return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
    }
}

Spring boot application pom file
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.gtt</groupId>
    <artifactId>converter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>converter</name>
    <description>converter</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Please find spring boot application log
Error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMessageListenerContainer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/config/annotation/SqsConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer]: Factory method 'simpleMessageListenerContainer' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'queueMessageHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/config/annotation/SqsConfiguration.class]: org/springframework/messaging/handler/annotation/support/PayloadArgumentResolver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer]: Factory method 'simpleMessageListenerContainer' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'queueMessageHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/config/annotation/SqsConfiguration.class]: org/springframework/messaging/handler/annotation/support/PayloadArgumentResolver
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'queueMessageHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/config/annotation/SqsConfiguration.class]: org/springframework/messaging/handler/annotation/support/PayloadArgumentResolver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:146) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/messaging/handler/annotation/support/PayloadArgumentResolver
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver

We are setting the SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory attribute in the bean but getting error while running application. the application build successfully, Can you please help us to resolve the issue.

Have you read the error? The Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver is pretty clear.The spring-cloud-starter-aws is old and not maintained anymore. There is now one from Amazon itself you should use.
